# Not fetching recent record inserted in hibernate

Tags: hibernate

I have an issue in fetching record from hibernate of recently created record.

Here creating Session factory :-

```
  public class HibernateUtil {
private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory;

static {
    try {
        sessionFactory = new 
AnnotationConfiguration().configure("hibernate.cfg.xml").buildSessionFactory();
    } catch (Throwable ex) {
        System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
        throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
    }
}

public Session openSession() {
    //System.out.println("GOign to get session");
    return sessionFactory.openSession();
}
}
```

here is the model class :-

```
    import java.io.Serializable;
   import java.util.List;

    import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
   import javax.persistence.Column;
   import javax.persistence.Entity;
   import javax.persistence.FetchType;
   import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
   import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
   import javax.persistence.Id;
   import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
   import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
  import javax.persistence.Table;
  @Entity
   @Table(name="clients")
 public class Clients implements Serializable  {
 @Id
 @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
 //file name started from capital letter bcoz of exist archtecture
 private Integer id;
 String clientname;
 String org_id;
String org_type;
 String sid;
String token;
Integer variable;
 String oauthrefreshtoken;
 String reg_date;
 String email;
String reminderone;
String remindertwo;
String reminderthree;
 String reminderfour;
Integer reminder ; //balance left after reminder to be sent
 Float paypalamount;
String activationdate;
 @OneToMany(cascade = { CascadeType.ALL},orphanRemoval=true)
 @JoinColumn(name="client_id")
List<SmsNumbers> smsNumbers;
```

and their getter and setter corresponding.
Below is my Dao class

```
  import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;

import org.hibernate.Criteria;
import org.hibernate.Query;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.criterion.Restrictions;

import com.smsapp.model.Clients;
 import com.smsapp.utility.HibernateUtil;

public class SmsDao {

public void addUpdateClients(Clients cli){
    HibernateUtil objHibernateUtil = new HibernateUtil();
    Session session=objHibernateUtil.openSession();
    try{
        session.beginTransaction();
        Clients cliObj=prepareObjToSaveOrUpdate(cli);
        session.saveOrUpdate(cliObj);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
    }catch(Exception ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally{
        session.close();    
    }
}

public Clients prepareObjToSaveOrUpdate(Clients cli)
{
    HibernateUtil objHibernateUtil = new HibernateUtil();
    Session session = objHibernateUtil.openSession();
    try{
        Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Clients.class);
        criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("org_id", cli.getOrg_id()));
        Clients clients = (Clients) criteria.uniqueResult();
        if (clients!=null) {
            removeOrphans(clients.getId());
            clients.getSmsNumbers().clear();
            return prepareObjectToUpdate(clients,cli);
        }
        else 
            return prepareObjectTOSave(cli);
    }finally {
        session.close();
    }

}
public Clients prepareObjectTOSave(Clients cli)
{
    cli.setVariable(1);  
    cli.setEmail("");
    cli.setReminderone("no"); 
    cli.setRemindertwo("no");   
    cli.setReminderthree("no");  
    cli.setReminderfour("no");   
    cli.setReminder(1);  
    cli.setPaypalamount(new Float(0));   
    cli.setActivationdate("");
    return cli;
}

public static void removeOrphans(Integer id)
{
    System.out.println("going to remove data");
    HibernateUtil objHibernateUtil = new HibernateUtil();
    Session session = objHibernateUtil.openSession();
    session.beginTransaction();
    Query query = session.createQuery("delete SmsNumbers where 
  client_id = :ID");
    query.setParameter("ID",id);
    int result = query.executeUpdate();
    session.getTransaction().commit();
    session.close();
    System.out.println("Data removed successfully");
}
public  Clients getClientByPhoneNumber(String phone)
{
    System.out.println("%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%\t"+phone);
    Clients cli=null;
    HibernateUtil objHibernateUtil = new HibernateUtil();
    Session session = objHibernateUtil.openSession();
    try{
        Criteria criteria=session.createCriteria(Clients.class);
        //criteria.createAlias("smsNumbers", "child");
        //criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("child.number", phone));

        List<Clients> lstCli=new ArrayList<Clients>();
        lstCli=criteria.list();
        System.out.println("%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%\t"+lstCli.size());
        if(lstCli!=null && lstCli.size()>0 &&  lstCli.get(0)!=null){
            //System.out.println("phone no matched in the database");
            cli= lstCli.get(0);
            System.out.println(cli.getId());
            return cli;
        }
    }catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        System.out.println(e);
        return null;
    }
    finally{
        session.close();
    }
    return cli;
  }
   }
```

After inserting a client when i fetch all the client then the recent created record in not fetched.

Answer (score 0):

```
I have just done:-
   session.clear() after commit transaction. 
   session.saveOrUpdate(cliObj);
   session.getTransaction().commit();
   session.clear();
```

And it work for me and now i can fetch the recent save record from the database.